# Class constructor defining inherited classes constructor syntax error in header file

Tags: c++

I have the below code giving me a syntax error on the `BindingSocket` definition, my understanding was if I wanted to define an inherited classes constructor I continue the `BindingSocket` definition with `BindingSocket(...):Socket(...);`, however this gives me a standard syntax error output.

```
#ifndef NETWORKING_BINDINGSOCKET_HPP_
#define NETWORKING_BINDINGSOCKET_HPP_

#include <stdio.h>
#include "Socket.hpp"

namespace HDE
{
    class BindingSocket: public Socket
    {
        public:
            BindingSocket(...) : Socket(...);
    };
}
```

and then within my main cpp file I can write:

```
HDE::BindingSocket::BindingSocket(...): Socket(...)
{
```

Strangely enough if I add a `{}` at the end of the header definition for the class I get no syntax error.

Comment: Do you mean this literally? `Socket(...)`?

Comment: no only decluttering the params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inheritance is given by `class BindingSocket: public Socket`.

The `: Socket(...)` after the constructor calls the parent constructor and belongs to the definition and not to the declaration.

So it has to be:

```
namespace HDE
{
    class BindingSocket: public Socket
    {
        public:
            BindingSocket(...);
    };
}
```

And:

```
HDE::BindingSocket::BindingSocket(...): Socket(...)
{
```

Comment: i see, many thanks